# Low forecast accuracy while using auto.arima for 15-minute interval data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, large-data

We are working with 3 years of 15minute time-interval media data (1million+ entries) and have 14 external regressors (daypart, weekdays, holiday, genres).
Objective is to forecast for next 15-minute intervals for given values of external regressors.
What we did:
- Used auto.arima (with xreg) from forecast package on this data. Result attached
[image]

- Created a sub-set of 5% of xreg data to check forecasting accuracy.
  When we compare actual media GRP values with forecasted values, there is high deviation of ~100% for certain data points.

  1. Is auto.arima the right approach for such large data?
  2. How can we improve accuracy of this model?

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to model your [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities) using a [bats](/questions/tagged/bats) or a [tbats](/questions/tagged/tbats) model, rather than with dummies. Then again, this might run into performance issues, given your large dataset.

You may be interested in [How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/222179/1352)

Other than that, I think we simply don't have enough information to be overly helpful.

Comment: Thanks Stephan for replying. However, we cannot remove these dummies, since the objective is to predict for given values of daypart, day, genre combinations. Eg: objective is to be able to predict TRP for a Comedy program (genre) aired on Tuesday (weekday) at Night (daypart).. Need your help how can I improve forecast here? also should I use Neural Networks?

Comment: A BATS or TBATS model will allow you to forecast for a given future time point, depending on the day of week and time of day that is. I suggest you take a look at that. Of course you can also use NNs.